# Missing header file while installing a C++ written program using terminal

Tags: macos, gcc, terminal, clang

I am trying to install wnd-charm (written in C++) using terminal. I have installed all its dependencies and I also have latest version of gcc and command line tools. I am following the instructions given on its documentation: https://github.com/wnd-charm/wnd-charm/blob/master/README.md

When I enter the final code:    `python setup.py build`

following error occurs:

```
> warning: include path for stdlibc++ headers not found; pass
> '-stdlib=libc++' on
>       the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead
>       [-Wstdlibcxx-not-found] wndcharm/swig/wndcharm_wrap.cpp:2767:10: fatal error: 'stdexcept' file not found 
> #include <stdexcept>
>       ^~~~~~~~~~~ 1 warning and 1 error generated. 
> error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

I know it has something to do with changing default standard library. I have tried every help available online.

Any help appreciated.

> macOS: 10.14.5
>
> Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 
>   (clang-1001.0.46.4) 
>   Target:x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0 Thread model: posix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `macOS` **Mojave** headers are no longer installed to `/usr/include` by default.

The following command should resolve the issue:

```
open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

> **Command Line Tools**
>   *New Features*
>
> - <sub>The Command Line Tools package
>     installs the macOS system headers inside the macOS SDK. Software that
>     compiles with the installed tools will search for headers within the
>     macOS SDK provided by either Xcode at:</sub>
>     
>
>    <sub>**/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk**</sub>
>     <sub>*or the Command Line Tools at:*
>
>
>     **/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk**</sub>
>
>   <sub>depending on which
>     is selected using **`xcode-select`**. The command line tools will search the
>     SDK for system headers by default. However, some software may fail to
>     build correctly against the SDK and require macOS headers to be
>     installed in the base system under **`/usr/include`**. If you are the
>     maintainer of such software, we encourage you to update your project
>     to work with the SDK or file a bug report for issues that are
>     preventing you from doing so. As a workaround, an extra package is
>     provided which will install the headers to the base system. In a
>     future release, this package will no longer be provided. You can find
>     this package at:</sub>
>     <sub>**/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg**</sub>
>     
>   <sub>To make sure that you're using the intended version of the command
>     line tools, run **`xcode-select -s <path to Xcode>`** or **`xcode select -s/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`** after installing.</sub>

↳ [Xcode 10 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes#overview)

Comment: I tried the command:   'open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg'  but the problem persists. Is there any other way out?

Comment: Eventually I manually copied the headers file to include folder and now its working ike charm.Thanks :)